# Get the values of macro expansion as understood by the compiler

Tags: c, visual-c++, gcc

I'm working with a code base that has a lot of macro that got defined and undefined and redefined all over the place. The compiler surprisingly is still able to chew through them, so is there anyway to extract this kind of macro expansion result , i.e.

```
MY_MACRO -> myFolder/myFile.cpp #266 float myFunc()
```

Is there  way to get this for both MSVC and GCC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `gcc -E` for GNU C/C++

For Visual Studio, you can use `CL /EP /C myfile.cpp` from a command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

For MSVC, compile with /P switch (Project > Properties > C/C++ > Preprocessor > Generate Preprocessed File). This generates the file (with .i extension) containing the text that the compiler proper actually sees, after all preprocessing directives are resolved.

I think on Unix-y platforms you could achieve the same with `cpp` tool.

Comment: Hi, I tried /P but the output is something like this `#line 1 "super-secret-location\\even-more-secret-file-name.c"` any idea how to interpret that?

Comment: #line directives allow you to figure out where in the original source files each line of preprocessed code comes from. The directive in your example tells you that the next line in the preprocessed output originally was line 1 in the file `even-more-secret-file-name.c` (and the line after that was line 2, and so on until the next #line directive).

Answer (score 0):

GDB lets you see the results of macros (see http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Macros.html).  But I don't know of anything that gives exactly what you're looking for.  Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, but gdb can't be used.